# Валидация PasswordBox WPF после выхода из системы

Tags: c#, wpf, валидация, password

У меня есть проверка пароля в приложении WPF. Я использую для этого интерфейс IDataErrorInfo. Существует xml-код с шаблоном проверки:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,-30,20,0" Height="23" Width="250" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
            </Border>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="Red" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" 
                        ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=Adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">!</TextBlock>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="Adorner" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ErrorViewerItemTemplate" DataType="string" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="5" Height="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="11" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="red" Padding="2" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Label x:Name="passLabel" Content="Password" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,40,0,0" Height="23">
            <PasswordBox local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="True" 
            x:Name="passwordBox" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword>
                    <Binding Path="Password" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" >
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <NotifyDataErrorValidationRule />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </local:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword>
            </PasswordBox>
        </Border>
</Grid>
```

Реализация интерфейса IDataErrorInfo для пароля:

```
class ConnectionSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _password;

    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _password;
        }
        set
        {
            _password = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
        }
    }

... // realization INotifyPropertyChanged interface

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string errorMessage = String.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                ...
                case "Password":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
                    {
                        errorMessage = "Validation error: Enter the data in the field";
                    }
                    else if (!RegexPasswordValid(Password))
                    {
                        errorMessage = "Validation error: The password does not match the template or short password (minimum 8 characters)";
                    }
                    break;
                 ...
            }
            return errorMessage;
        }
    }

    private bool RegexPasswordValid(string value)
    {
        string pattern = @"^(\w{8,})$";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        bool isRegexValid = (regex.IsMatch(value)) ? true : false;
        return isRegexValid;
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
```

Для привязки (биндинга) пароля я использую [PasswordBoxAssistant class](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html).

Валидация пароля при первом входе в систему работает правильно 
[image]

но когда пользователь выходит из системы - проверка пароля на окне входа в систему не работает.

[image]

Я попыталася установить `Mode ="TwoWay"` для биндинга и `ValidatesOnDataErrors = True, ValidatesOnExceptions = True`, но это не устранило мою проблему.

Пожалуйста, помогите мне исправить это хотя бы как-то.)

Comment: Отладчик что говорит?

Comment: @АндрейNOP в каком смысле? Вы о том становятся ли значения свойств пароля и других полей нулевыми после лог аута? Да, они стают null.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, вы брейкпоинт в индексатор ставили? Выполняется ли он вообще? А пароль как очищаете? В VM? В общем пока мало что понятно. Вы можете предоставить такой минимальный пример, который бы я у себя мог запустить и увидеть проблему без додумывания?

Comment: @АндрейNOP [Вот пример.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WtKjd03BNZR0IefyXZK4yVLHcoNAu2G9)
 Я в вопросе не указала, но я использую еще и  user settings для логина и пароля. На счет MVVM, я знаю, что здесь я его немного нарушаю, так как только недавно начала работать с WPF. =(

Comment: Ну да, индексатор для поля Password после логаута не вызывается. Да и вообще он не вызывается для Password

Comment: @АндрейNOP и каким образом это можно пофиксить? Подскажите пожалуйста.)

Comment: Пытаюсь разобраться пока

Comment: @АндрейNOP и еще что интересно, я в регулярке опредилила, что пароль должен быть длиной минимум 8 символов, а уведомление об ошибке исчезает уже после того как введеш один символ в поле

Comment: Ну дык я ж говорю, что индексатор не вызывается при вводе текста в пассвордбокс. Похоже ваш PasswordBoxAssistant нерабочий.

Comment: Поставьте брейкпоинт в сеттер `Password` и убедитесь, что он не вызывается при вводе текста в пассвордбокс

Comment: @АндрейNOP я думаю, что проблема кроется в использовании класса PasswordBoxAssistant. Потому что валидация в поле логина исполняется так же как и в поле пароля, только в поле логина все работает верно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш `PasswordBoxAssistant` не работает.

Я использую для привязки пароля такое:

```
public class BindablePasswordBox : Decorator
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Password), typeof(string), typeof(BindablePasswordBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnPasswordPropertyChanged));

    static void OnPasswordPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var bpb = (BindablePasswordBox)d;
        if (bpb.isPreventCallback) return;
        bpb.passwordBox.PasswordChanged -= bpb.HandlePasswordChanged;
        bpb.passwordBox.Password = (string)eventArgs.NewValue;
        bpb.passwordBox.PasswordChanged += bpb.HandlePasswordChanged;
    }

    bool isPreventCallback = false;
    PasswordBox passwordBox = new PasswordBox();

    public BindablePasswordBox()
    {
        passwordBox.PasswordChanged += HandlePasswordChanged;
        Child = passwordBox;
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(PasswordProperty);
        set => SetValue(PasswordProperty, value);
    }

    void HandlePasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        isPreventCallback = true;
        Password = passwordBox.Password;
        isPreventCallback = false;
    }
}
```

После замены PasswordBox на эту реализацию, ваш пример заработал как надо:

```
<local:BindablePasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" ...>
    <local:BindablePasswordBox.Password>
        <Binding Path="Password" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <NotifyDataErrorValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </local:BindablePasswordBox.Password>
</local:BindablePasswordBox>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!)